# how to cc someone without actually sending to the cc in php

Tags: php, email

Hey guys I have a email sender and my boss brought up a idea that I was hoping to accomplish, is there anyway to cc someone without the message being sent to the cc?

So for instance:

```
to: test@test.com
cc: t@t.com <---- test@test.com should see he got cc'd but t@t.com should not receive this
```

David

Comment: Don't CC's get emailed by default? Isn't that how email works?

Comment: Ya but is there a way to stop that?

Comment: Like maybe in the config file or something?

Comment: How do you plan on notifying the user that he was CC'd then?

Comment: One solution: talk smtp directly to the receiving server / mx of the `to:` address ahd put a mail there with the appropriate headers, but don't send it to any _actual_ MTA to handle it. This means you have to be prepared for greylisting, resending on failure, and all kinds of other problems MTA's usually handle for you.

Comment: well for this particular function they don't want to recieve the cc, lets just say its to scare the employee?

Comment: Is this moral? Personally, I think it's reprehensible behaviour, especially within a business

Comment: Haha, I am just doing my job.  Is there anyway to stop this?

Comment: @DavidBiga lamest excuse ever - if `t@t.com` doesn't actually want to see these mails, install a filter on his mail program that automatically bins every mail sent by `test@test.com` where `t@t.com` is cc'ed.  And find yourself a job where da boss doesn't spend money on scaring employees.

Comment: I will honor my boss :)  but I do agree...I will see what we can come up with...the screening idea sounds good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that no, if you cc someone on an email, they will get the email, there's no magic flag to 'dont actually send to people ccd'

The best you might hope for is if you have access to the mail server, and modify that to not send cc's, but that would be a server wide change, so later on when you actually DO want to cc someone... bad luck

This might help you out, it shows how to NOT send to the TO email, only to the CC https://superuser.com/questions/156532/smtp-is-it-possible-to-cc-someone-without-sending-the-original

Comment: Cool, just made an edit to the answer to add a link to another post that may help

Answer (score 1):

If it's just that the CC address wants to be notified when that e-mail is sent. Aren't you better off just to send him a different message like "`e-mail` was sent `blah`"?